# keyboard shortcuts not responding in vb.net2010

Tags: vb.net

This does not work on my application. Funny thing is, it does not give off an error either.

```
Private Sub frmMain_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        MsgBox("A pressed")
    End If
End Sub
```

I have seen where people use this in videos and it worked for them. I do not know why mine does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the [`KeyPreview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the form to true.

valter